# Need To Insert a Digital Count-down timer in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint

Need some advice please, I need to insert a simple count down timer or digital clock in PowerPoint 2010 and must be in the following format:

Countdown to project go-live:
DDD-HH-MM-SS

Need it to count down remaining days, hours, min until 31st May.

As this needs to be in PowerPoint,  I can only use a custom template or Flash object, not HTML script.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at [Clocks and timers for PowerPoint](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00081_Clocks_and_timers_for_PowerPoint.htm)?

Comment: All I could find was some reference to installing Dynamic time plugin for PowerPoint but could not actually find how or where to install this from, any suggestions?  Thanks David.

Comment: The page David linked to doesn't even include the word Dynamic; I'm not sure what you're referring to.  But it does include a link to VBA code from Shyam Pillai that can probably be adapted to what you want.